# HyperV VMs in BackingUp status during R1Soft Backup task run time

Tags: hyper-v, r1soft

I have a HyperV installed on windows server 2016. VMs are created and running successfully. Setup a R1soft policy in my Backup server to backup the entire image of HyperV server which includes the disk drive stores vhdx files of VMs.

Now my problem is when the r1soft policy rans, all VMs in the server will be backing up stage, and I am not able to manage VMs (like start,stop etc) during the period of r1soft backup task runs. backing up status will only change to normal either backup task completes or cancel the backup task.

Any idea why this behavior happening?.  When I googled the same, I see comments like it may related to enabled volume shadow copy of disk or hypverV integration service or due to volume shadow copy service requester service.

But not sure what exactly need to be checked.  Any valuable comments will be much appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

What worked for me as a work around was to restart hyper v virtual Machine management service from services.msc

If the service went to mode stopping I kill the pid by issuing the command:

```
sc queryex vmms : note pid 

taskkill /f /pid pidnumber from above command
```

Then start the service hyper v virtual Machine management.